# как остановить заданный interval в JS

Tags: javascript

Есть есть ряд черных квадратных div'ов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача поймать клик на одном из них и с интервалом в 1 сек перекрасить их в красный цвет. и после перекраски последнего div'a остановиться.

вот код с комментами:

```js
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.square'); // получаем все квадраты

    for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) // пробегаем по div'ам, слушаем клик 
    {
        divs[i].addEventListener('click', () => {

            setInterval(recolorNextOne, 1000); // с интервалом в 1сек перекрашиваем соседние div'ы в красный

            function recolorNextOne()
            {
                divs[i++].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                if(i == (divs.length))
                {
                    clearInterval(recolorNextOne, 1000); // очищаем интервал (!!!)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Все работает, по клику блоки перекрашиваются, но вот как раз проблема с завершением. По достижении цели, интервал не прекращается и в консоли с интервалом в 1 сек вылетает ошибка, мол пытаюсь "перекрасить" несуществующий div.

подскажите, как реализовать задуманное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую подробно почитать про [`setInterval`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval), там сказано:

> Чтобы остановить дальнейшее выполнение функции, необходимо вызвать `clearInterval(timerId)`.

Где `timerId` является переменная с запуском таймера, в вашем случае правильный код будет выглядеть так:

```
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.square'); // получаем все квадраты

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) // пробегаем по div'ам, слушаем клик 
{
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', () => {

    let timerId = setInterval(recolorNextOne, 1000);
    // с интервалом в 1сек перекрашиваем соседние div'ы в красный

    function recolorNextOne() {
      divs[i++].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      if (i == (divs.length)) {
        clearInterval(timerId); // очищаем интервал (!!!)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо, ни один учебник по JS мне не смог так легко помочь)

Comment: Есть это в учебниках: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval после заголовка итого, так же в справочнике: https://javascript.ru/clearInterval